# Unable to locate sass file

Tags: python, html, django, sass

I have a sass file in my django project, the path inside my project is the following: Project\Project\static\style\Login.scss but when i run the command python manage.py runserver i get the following error message:

"Unable to locate file Login.scss while rendering tag 'sass_src' in template None"

but when i create the sass file inside the following path "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static " my webpage can identify my sass file and work normally.

how can i do to make my webpage identify the sass file that is located in a folder inside the project like the following: "Project\Project\static\style\"

---------------- html ------------------------------

```
{% load sass_tags %}

<html>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% sass_src 'Login.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  >
    </header>
```

---------------- setting.py ------------------------------

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sass_processor',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'CvProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CvProject.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIR = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'CvProject/static')
]


STATIC_ROOT = "/CvProject/static"
# Django Sass
#SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'CvProject/static')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `Login.scss` as your filepath when you said it is located in `style/file.scss`?

try changing this:

```
{% sass_src 'Login.scss' %}
```

to this:

```
{% sass_src 'style/Login.scss' %}
```

Comment: about the name it was a typing mistake. i made the changes but it still don't work out the path  "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static"

Comment: @denilsonbarahona did you try adding `style/` to the filepath?

Comment: if you mean like this {% sass_src 'style/Login.scss' %}.. yes i did and it still doesn´t work

Comment: it only works when i link the sass file like this <link href="{% sass_src 'Login.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  >  and also if the sass file is located in the following path "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static " this is the  python's instalation path  .... but i would like to located my sass file inside the folder in my project path. in a path like this "Project\Project\static\style\".